# How to specify exponential constants in C#?

Tags: c#, constants, numeric, exponential

I've got some C code that defines a exponential number as a constant. How do I write this in C#?

```
    double TOL = 1.E-8d;
    double TOL2 = 1.E - 8;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there are no numbers after the decimal, you don't include the point. Same as in C/C++/etc. So:

```
double TOL= 1E-8;
double TOL2 = 1E-8;
```

Or maybe, for a different value:

```
double TOL = 1.5E-8;
```

This is in the spec, section 2.4.4.3:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx

Comment: More informative (about topic) link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/lexical-structure#real-literals

Answer (score 3):

```
    double tol = 1.0e8;
    double tol2 = 1.0e-8;
```

Answer (score 3):

You were very close with your first form - but you just needed a digit after the ".", or remove the "." entirely:

```
double TOL = 1.0E-8d;
double TOL = 1E-8d;
```

See section 2.4.4.3 of the [C# language spec](https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/viewer?url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/D/0BDA894F-2CCD-4C2C-B5A7-4EB1171962E5/CSharp%2520Language%2520Specification.doc) for the rules around this. Note that you can use a lower-case "e" if you want, too:

```
double TOL = 1.0e-8d;
double TOL = 1e-8d;
```

And double is the default type if you omit the suffix from a "real" literal, so these are valid too:

```
double TOL = 1.0e-8;
double TOL = 1e-8;
```

... but personally I'd include the suffix for readability.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do it in C#:

```
double value = -4.42330604244772E-305;
```

See also [MSDN on System.Double](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different example, and not for exponential numbers.

`double value = 1744056d`  is reported as error by g++ on Linux.

`double value = 1744056.0d` is fine.